# ¿Por que me devuelve el numero menor?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código simple que acabo de crear, el código tiene la finalidad de decirte el número más alto entre los dos que sean insertados. EL código funciona hasta el 99, por ejemplo, si yo coloco 6 y 99 te muestra 99 como mayor pero si coloco 6 me muestra el menor ¿Por que es eso?

Acá les dejo el código:

```
function maxnum(one,two) {
        if (one > two){
            return one;
        } else 
            return two;
    }
    var uno
    var dos
    alert('Introduzca 2 numeros para decir cual es mayor');
    uno = prompt();
    dos = prompt();

    alert(maxnum(uno,dos));
```

Tengo 2 preguntas:

¿Por que pasa esto?
¿Donde tengo el error?

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices que si coloco 6 me devuelve el menor? o sea si colocas : maxnum(6,6) a eso? expresa mejor tu pregunta. para poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola @rodman99 ¿Está completo el código? Observa que tu método `maxnum()` no tiene una llave de cierre antes de las llamadas `prompt()` . Por ahora, no veo claro por qué se ejecuta.

Comment: El algoritmo hace su funcion de devolverme el numero mayor, por ejemplo si yo coloco 6 y 99 me dice que el numero mayor es 99 pero cuando coloco un numero del 100 en adelante por ejemplo 6  101 me dice que 6 es el mayor en vez de decirme el 100

Copia el codigo y ejecutalo en tu navegador para que me puedas entender mejor

Comment: Los invito a que ejecuten el script en su propio navegador, para que vean el error

Comment: Coloquen cualquier numero menor a 100 y uno de 100 en adelante para que vean que en vez de devolverle el numero mayor que seria el que coloquen mayor a 100 les va a decir que el mayor es el que colocaron menor a 100

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow... Tu código no tiene ningun problema de llaves como dice uno de los comentarios. y de hecho esta casi casi correcto. Tu problema fue el clásico problema del tipo de dato. Al usar el prompt() no estas indicando el tipo de dato, por el cual simplemente estas comparando caracteres. Para que tu código funcione solo basta con parsear a entero el prompt() o castearlo a *Number*. Te voy a poner el ejemplo con el casteo para que hagas la prueba desde aquí:

```js
function maxnum(one,two) {
    if (one > two){
        return one;
    } else 
        return two;
}
var uno
var dos
alert('Introduzca 2 numeros para decir cual es mayor');
uno = (Number)(prompt());// aquí es donde se castea el valor del prompt()
dos = (Number)(prompt());// aquí es donde se castea el valor del prompt()

alert(maxnum(uno,dos));
```

---

**ACLARACION:**
Para responder porque aun siendo caracteres '6' es mayor a '100' puedes hacer la prueba desde la consola del navegador la siguiente linea de codigo:

`'6'.charCodeAt(0) > '100'.charCodeAt(0)`

El resultado de esta linea es *True* (osea que 6 el mayor a 100). Si desarmamos esa linea en dos partes seria:

`'6'.charCodeAt(0)` que es igual a 54 en el codigo ASCII

y

`'100'.charCodeAt(0)` que es igual a 49 en el codigo ASCII

... es por eso que `54 > 49`.

Pero hay que hacer la aclaración que `100` no es un carácter sino es una cadena de caracteres, y ese 49 no pertenece al `100` sino solo al `1` de ese 100 (implícitamente toma el primer carácter de la cadena)

Te reitero, podes reproducirlo en la consola de tu navegador para verificar:

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]